# Cooking thawed fish when it says cook from frozen?

Tags: fish, frozen

I have a pack of fish in the fridge that says cook from frozen, is it safe to cook now it has defrosted. I have had it for one day in the fridge

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is safe.
You might have to adjust the cooking timing that is suggested though.

Answer (score 1):

It is safe, but I would not leave it in the fridge much more than one day. Also make certain it is fully cooked through. If you like your fish a bit rare, but fresh and cook as soon as possible.

Answer (score -1):

if only one day defrosting and kept in fridge it should be ok still to cook BUT any ODOUR emanating from it after rinsing it is a good guide. // Fresh fish Doesn't really smell "fishy"…

Comment: Honestly it really depends on the species of fish - for example a shorelunch made from northern pike the meat will smell fishy despite being dead only minutes as a result of the fish's natural odour. This is an over generalization and may not be applicable to the species in question by the OP.